# Why am I getting "ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis" on an SOQL query from a managed package

Tags: apex, soql, managed-package, permissions

I am getting the following error when calling an Apex controller accessor from a managed package.

```
System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
```

Here is a simplified version of the Apex controller

```
public with sharing virtual class MyController {

    public String getAccountId() {
        // It fails on this query
        List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT AccountID FROM Contact WHERE Id IN (SELECT ContactId FROM User WHERE Id = :UserInfo.getUserId())];

        if (contacts.size() > 0) {
            return contacts.get(0).accountId;
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

It happens only when:

- user has a profile with limited privileges
- the controller is in a managed package

### Some of the things I tried so far

- reproduced the issue with many users having the same profile.
- it works fine for admin users
- the same SOQL query works fine outside of the managed package. It was tested with a custom VisualForce page and Apex controller (with limited user).
- executing `UserInfo.getUserId()` from the custom controller works fine and returns a valid user ID.
- executing the sub-query alone from the custom controller works fine. It returns a single user where `contactId` is `null`.
- [this page](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_user.htm) mentions many special cases involving portal users. At this moment, I don't think it is related because I would expect the query to fail in the custom code as well.

Do you have any idea what could cause the `ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis` error?

Thanks for your help

Comment: This is a generic syntax error from an Oracle database deep in the guts of SF infrastructure. Apex code isn't supposed to see this type of error. It might be a temporary issue or a genuine bug in SF platform.  You should open a support case and let them know.

Comment: Have you tried replacing the function call in the binding with a simple binding variable initialized from that function call?

Comment: @PhilW I tried that, but using custom code, not the managed package. In Salesforce documentation, I found many occurrences of similar SOQL queries that use `UserInfo.getUserId()` the same way, so expressions seem to be well supported.

Comment: @identigral Thanks for the advice, the error message sound pretty internal indeed. I'll file a case with Salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

This is my *guess*.

This field is only accessible when Digital Experiences (previously known as Communities) are enabled:

```
SELECT ContactId FROM User
```

So I suggest making the queries and code as simple and defensive as possible to work around this problem:

```
public Id getAccountId() {
    Id contactId = queryContactId();
    if (contactId != null) {
        for (Contact c : [
                SELECT AccountID
                FROM Contact
                WHERE ID = :contactId
                ]) {
            return c.AccountId;
        }
    }
}

// Defensively find the ContactId for the Digital Experience User
private Id queryContactId() {
    SObjectType field = Contact.SObjectType.getDescribe().fields.getMap().get('ContactId');
    if (field != null) {
        if (field.getDescribe().isAccessible()) {
            Id userId = UserInfo.getUserId();
            for (User u : [
                    SELECT ContactId
                    FROM User
                    WHERE Id = :userId
                    ]) {
                return u.ContactId;
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: I'll double check the Digital Experiences and see if the `contactId` is really present or not. I'm still wondering why the SOQL query executes fine from custom code, and not from the package though.

Comment: Hi @LucBergeron, Running in the same org and under the same user? Profiles/licenses have a big impact.

Comment: I confirm, the tests are performed with the same org and user.